# How to insert another table data from select query for exist table

Tags: ms-access-2007, c#-3.0

Actually I'm creating one database application where if person first day login then his `sales_count` will be 1, same person login again then its `sales_count` will be 2 , same user login next day then its `sales_count` again 1.

For this I created two tables `Login` and `Sales_Details`. In Login I have:

> User_name, Password and Unique no.

Now, in `sales_details` I want to fetch only `User_name`,`Unique_no` from login detail but at same time I want to increment `sales_count` in `sales_details` table also update today date.

Sales_details has

> Sales_id,User_name,Unique_No,Sales_count,To_Date field

Actually I tried but nothing happen if To_date is null then insert today date+sales_count as 1 in sales_details

Below I'm pasting my whole code:

```
string todaydate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
string access = "select To_Date from Sales_Details";
cmd = new OleDbCommand(access, con);
con.Open();
using (OleDbDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
    while (read.Read()){
       string date2 = read["To_Date"].ToString();
       if (todaydate == date2){
           cmd = new OleDbCommand("update Sales_Details set Sales_count= IIF(IsNull(Sales_count), 0, Sales_count) + 1, [To_Date]=Date() where [Unique_No]=@Unique_No", con);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique_No", txtinput.Text);
           con.Open();
           int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           if (n == 0) {
               MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No.");
           } else {
               this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
           }
           con.Close();
      } else {
           int counter=1;
           cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into Sales_Details select User_name,Unique_No from Login where Unique_No=@Unique_No Union select ISNULL(Sales_Count+1,0) as [@Sales_Count],DATE() AS [To_date]", con);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unique_No", txtinput.Text);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sales_count",counter);
           int n1 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           if (n1 == 0){                                                            
               MessageBox.Show("Invalid Unique No.");
           } else {
               this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
           }
           }
      }
 }
 con.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create insert query with select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934997/how-to-create-insert-query-with-select-statement)

Comment: @GordThompson : Actually i want to delete that thread but i unable to do that because in that thread im not properly explain my question .. sorry for that

Comment: I formatted the code, I feel that there is an extra } . please check again.